# How to sort <table> data with PHP

Tags: php, sorting

One of the things I need to do on an assignment is showing information about registered users in a table. It has to be sorted in different ways by clicking buttons (gender, first name, last name, ...).

I'm writing this in PHP. The only thing I came up with is working with different pages, but  I would get about 20 different pages.

What would be the best way to implement this? A different page for every order type?
 
I've never worked with jQuery, but it would seem it would be good for this sort of thing?

Comment: does data come from a database?

Comment: If you **can** use jQuery to complete your assignment, have a look at [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) or [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually this is done with a database, in which case, you can use a language like MySQL to `ORDER BY`, and this will do it for you.

If you're in PHP only (per your question), try using one of the [many-available PHP Array sort options here](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

Comment: Yes, but the way I see it I would still need to do access a new function, so I would need a new page right ? I'm on  Postgres

Comment: @Lucas - No - the same function is used - depending on which link you click to sort, it passes the function a different variable to sort on.

Answer (score 2):

a good plugin for jQuery is [TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of javascript and php combination for simple values processing:

make a your_file.php, insert this code, and upload to your folder. (using this [sortable.js](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js) script )

```
<html><head>
<script src="sorttable.js"></script>

<style>
tbody tr td {color:green;border-right:1px solid;width:200px;}
</style>
</head><body>

<?php
$First = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$Second = array('1', '2', '3', '4');

if (!empty($_POST['myFirstvalues'])) 
{ $First = explode("\r\n",$_POST['myFirstvalues']); $Second = explode("\r\n",$_POST['mySecondvalues']);}

?>

</br>Hi User. PUT your values</br></br>
<form action="" method="POST">
projectX</br>
<textarea cols="20" rows="20" name="myFirstvalues" style="width:200px;background:url(untitled.PNG);position:relative;top:19px;Float:left;">
<?php foreach($First as $vv) {echo $vv."\r\n";}?>
</textarea>

The due amount</br>
<textarea cols="20" rows="20" name="mySecondvalues" style="width:200px;background:url(untitled.PNG);Float:left;">
<?php foreach($Second as $vv) {echo $vv."\r\n";}?>
</textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<table class="sortable" style="padding:100px 0 0 300px;">
<thead style="background-color:#999999; color:red; font-weight: bold; cursor: default;  position:relative;">
  <tr><th>ProjectX</th><th>Due amount</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
foreach($First as $indx => $value) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$First[$indx].'</td><td>'.$Second[$indx].'</td></tr>';
}
?>
</tbody>
<tfoot><tr><td>TOTAL  = &nbsp;<b>111111111</b></td><td>Still to spend  = &nbsp;<b>5555555</b></td></tr></tfoot></br></br>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```